# Partial segue on subview

Tags: ios

Currently I'm switching in subviews by animating a property of the subview (e.g. opacity, x, y etc.). What I'm wondering is whether there is a neater way to do this?

When I didn't need just a subview loaded, I used storyboard segues, where I could just pick a style. Is there something like that for just subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using `[UIView transitionWithView:]` and `[UIView transitionFromView:]`. I should have read the documentation before posting.